# Prestashop and Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop uses by default mysql. So my question is, exist some plugin or project to install prestashop 1.6 with postgresql instead mysql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prestashop doesn't support Postgresql unfortunately. And I don't know any plugin that does that.

Here is a link on the forge with that demand : [Prestashop and DB PostgreSQL V1.5](http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-2785). Its priority is `minor`.

A very interessing study about the [feasibility](http://www.interdb.jp/techinfo/prestashop/study01.html).

---

---

### Here are the titles of this study :

1. Back quote (`) problem (non-standard: MySQL expand)
2. Table Definitions (Data Type : `UNSIGNED`, `auto_increment`, `ENUM` - `CREATE TABLE`)
3. INSERT ( `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, `INSERT IGNORE`, `INSERT INTO table () VALUES ()`)
4. `REPLACE` (non-standard: MySQL expand)
5. SELECT (`Last_Insert_Id`, `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, `IF(), IFNULL()`)
6. `UPDATE LIMIT`, `DELETE LIMIT` statements     (non-standard: MySQL expand)
7. SHOW commands

### 3 important issues:

1. How to change `Db::insert` method.
2. How to emulate `last_insert_id()` function.
3. How to rewrite `UPDATE/DELETE LIMIT` logic.